# Patch / replace linux kernel in memory

Tags: linux, memory, patch

I have ARM-based device with linux on-board. Its very difficult to flash custom kernel for some reasons (uBoot cant load kernel via tftp or something else)

I need to test my custom kernel.
So, idea is - replace kernel in memory. How do you think, is it possible?

Tell me any suggestions please.

Comment: have you tried `kexec`

Comment: There is no kexec system call in installed kernel. May be i must write kernel module with needed functions?

Comment: even if you succeed at loading your kernel in memory, you then have to boot from it without rebooting your board ... and that's quite a feat to achieve ... hopefully you can look at how they did exactly that with kexec. might give you ideas.

Comment: i think i should try overwrite kernel memory from kernel module and then make soft reset. (processor has soft-reset) Hope it will work =) kexec looks like work similar

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [link](http://www.ksplice.com/)

It's for a project called Ksplice that allows one to patch a running kernel.

At one point this code was open, but Oracle bought it...  So they may have closed it up and made it cost money.  If that's the case, look around and see if you can find the formerly open code in the wild...